# Расчет MD5 для объекта

Tags: java, хеширование, md5

Можно ли рассчитать MD5 для объекта (стандартный `java` класс), отличного от массива байт?

Нужно как вариант определения изменялся ли : `javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument`

Comment: Привести объект к массиву байт?)

Comment: автор пожалуйста добавьте какую глобальную проблему спасения мира вы решаете пытаясь сделать хэш обьекта

Comment: @jmu Вообще расчет MD5 рассматриваю как один из вариантов решания всей проблемы, думал, это будет проще всего. Если кто-то знает лучше способ, буду благодарен за подсказку

Comment: Вы изначально поставили неправильно вопрос. Не зря метод hashcode называется так, и извлечении md5 из обекта (т.е выполнении функции хеширования) это конечно же придумывание велосипеда. 
В любом случае, я против сереализации обьекта, - нет гарантий что не будут сериализированы какие-то внутренние временные данные, которые могут привести к неверным результатам

Answer (score 4):

[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow) прав. Достаточно [сериализовать](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) произвольный объект в массив байт, а затем высчитать на его основе хэш. При этом необходимо реализовать в просчитываемом объекте интерфейс Serializable.

Comment: прошу прощения за некорректно заданный вопрсо - класс входит в swing, т.е. он создан не мной и реализовать Serializable я не могу, только если сделать наследника, но это как-то криво

Answer (score 2):

если все обьекты имеют одинаковый тип то они идентифицируются по хешкоду обьекта:

```
new Object().hashcode();
```

поэтому достаточно md5 функции подсунуть hashcode обьекта.

в виду последних камментов, проверка состояния обьекта:
1) добавляем функцию (в каком-то воспомагательном классе) которая проверяет состояние всех полей обьекта (с помощью reflection можно будетп роверить даже private)
2) пронаследоватся от класса с которым вы работаете и в методы которые меняют сосотяние обьекта добавляете код который будет отслеживать изменение состояния обьекта (если не ошибаюсь это шаблоны proxy или facade)

**UPDATE**: а в целом, если вашей задачей является следить за изменением состояния обьекта, то вам нужен шаблон observer (google: observer design pattern)

Comment: как написано в спецификации джава код new Object().hashcode(); вернет числовое представление ссылки на объект, это раз, а, во-вторых, объект класса, который написан не мной и метод hashcode я не смогу вызвать

Comment: 1. ссылок на объект может быть несколько, но обьект то один  
 2. обьект класса может быть написан хоть папой карло. в любом случае 2 варианта: а) он возвращает как описано в базовом классе Object b) разработчик класса все таки позаботился и возвращает уникальное значение через hashcode. хотя может быть такое, что у разных обьектов один и тот же хешкод, - но это только в том случае, если это необходимая логика приложения  
 3. назовите хотя бы одну разумную причину, почему вы не сможете вызвать метод hashcode для какого-то обьекта?

Comment: 1. Согласен, немного перепутал, `new Object().hashcode()` вернет адрес
 2. Разработчик используемого мной класса не позаботился (`javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument`)
 3. Мне надо определить, изменилось ли состояние, при повторном вызове `hashcode()` в моем случае каждый раз я буду получать постоянный адрес объекта

Answer (score 1):

Может имеет смысл написать функцию, которая бы доставала интересующие вас свойства объекта, включая его hashcode(), и хешировала бы через MD5 именно эти параметры?

Чтобы было проще, скажите, объект какого класса(ов) вы хотите хешировать?

Comment: Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой, у меня есть javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument, мне надо определить после определенного события изменялся он или нет, просто getText() тут не подходит, т.к. необходимо учитывать и изменение стиля, даже если я извлеку параметры(а это тоже отдельная история) - это также классы джавы, которые не я создавал и не могу их сериализовать. Вообще расчет MD5 рассматриваю как один из вариантов решания всей проблемы, думал, это будет проще всего. Если кто-то знает лучше способ, буду благодарен за подсказку

Comment: Ознакомление с темой "java рефлексия" поможет Вам. 

В Java можно "разобрать" любой объект на составные части (вплоть до примитивов). По их значениям считайте свою MD5.

Вопрос тут в том, какие части javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument Вам нужны (это уже зависит от задачи).

Comment: @avp, еще раз: внутри  javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument поля, которые также представляют из себя классы джава, которые я не смогу преобразовать в массив байт

Comment: Наберите в Google "java рефлексия", почитайте, осознайте и Вы успешно справитесь с данной задачей.